# TFS Changeset by multiple users

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I have been working TFS API to get all workitems related to all changesets between a particular  month. Then through changeset objects, I have used commiterDisplaName property to filter out a particular group of users say "foo1,foo2,foo3".

This is a lot time consuming since it first extracts all changesets and then through a loop tries to filter out workitems of each changeset through the name of the user.

Is there a way in TFS API where I can only get the changesets done by multiple users directly?
I have searched through MSDN on this one but till now no luck on this one.

This would surely reduce the loop filtering through username which is very time consuming.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are just using a basic for each loop then using a lambda may help a little.  Could you post what you have so far?

Comment: Which API are using? VersionControlServer.QueryHistory?

Comment: Yes I am using VersionControlServer.QueryHistory. I am retrieving all changesets of a particular month of all existing users from QueryHistoy method. All Changeset objects retrieved from TFS are then looped to check with a list of usernames and if they exist then I cache the WorkItems of the changeset to process more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VersionControlServer.QueryHistory have an overload of [signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138960.aspx)

```
public IEnumerable QueryHistory(
    string path,
    VersionSpec version,
    int deletionId,
    RecursionType recursion,
    string user,
    VersionSpec versionFrom,
    VersionSpec versionTo,
    int maxCount,
    bool includeChanges,
    bool slotMode
)
```

Notice the 5th parameter user. So you can query changesets of specific user as

```
var changesets = vcServer.QueryHistory(
    "<your local path>", VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full,
    @"domain\user", null, null, 10, false, false);
```

However, this `user` parameter doesn't support multiple users. I don't think any other TFS API support multiple users either. So you can loop through users list and retrieve chagnesets of each user. There is still a loop, but it should much faster compared to querying all changesets.